# SOAP-UI - How to pass parameter from variable

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xxx="http://xxx.call/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cotf:call_XXX>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <parameter1>some value1</parameter1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <parameter2>some value2</parameter2>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <parameter3>some value3</parameter3>
         </arg0>
      </cotf:call_XXX>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I would like to know is how I can pass a variable instead of some value1,some value2,some value3 and how can I set these variable values from a response of another webservice

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieved this using properties, there are some scopes for the properties project, testCase, testSuite, etc. You've to set the property name and the value at desired scope and then you can use it directly in your request using the follow notation `${#scope#propertyname}` for example if you've a property called `parameter1` at testCase scope, you can use it in your request as follows:

```
...
<arg0>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <parameter1>${#TestCase#parameter1}</parameter1>
...
```

[image]

For more info take a look [at the documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html).

As you also ask to fill this property from the response of other testStep a possible way to achieved is using **property transfer step**, at this step you've to set:

1. Source: TestStep and it's property (response, request, etc.).
2. `XPATH` to perform against the source to get the value.
3. The target property where you put the recovered value: scope and property name.

[image]

I expand the second part with an example, so imagine you've a testStep which has `myRequest` as name and its responds looks like:

```
<myResponse>
   <someValue>MyValue</someValue>
   <anotherText>someText</anotherText>
</myResponse>
```

You want to get the value of `<anotherText>` node to reuse it so the `XPath` to get it from the response `//*:anotherText`. Then you put the value inside a property called `parameter1` at `TestCase` level (i.e the testCase is named `TestCase 1`). In this scenario the property transfer step will be:

- Source: `myRequest` Property: `Response`
- XPATH: `//*:anotherText`
- Target: `TestCase 1` Property: `parameter1`

For more info take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/teststep-reference/property-transfers.html) and [here](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html)

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I understood the first part.But coming to setting the property using property transfer step,could you please elaborate how to achieve this or give me link which describing the same

Comment: @user136252 ok I'll expand the second part `:)`.

Comment: 2 useful notes: For dynamic property values you can set property values to ${=groovy script} e.g. something like ${=String.valueOf(Math.random()*10000000).substring(0,5)}. For script in MockService response use getNodeValue to read value from incoming request and set the value in context. Then you can use the context variable (e.g. here ${id}) in  response. def holder = oGroovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent); id = holder.getNodeValue("//*:deliverRequest/@id");
context.setProperty( "id", id );