# Transfer variable to TestStep SOAPUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am trying to use a groovy script to create a variable and then transfer it to a SOAP request in a subsequent step.

This is my groovy Script - TestStep **InputVariables**:

```
def nextStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Add")

def first = 88
def second = 12

def res = nextStep.run(testRunner, context)

log.info res
```

Then in the SOAP step (TestStep **Add**) I try to use the variables this way (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066042/soap-ui-how-to-pass-parameter-from-variable)):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>"${#InputVariables#first}"</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>"${#InputVariables#second}"</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But it is not working. This is the response I receive:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (5, 33). ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&amp; number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read1_Add()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: No idea, but have you tried removing the `"` from around `${#InputVariables#first}` and `${#InputVariables#second}`?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes I tried that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was a little different than in the linked question. I modified the script this way:

```
def nextStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Add")

Integer first = 88
Integer second = 12

context.first = first
context.second = second

def res = nextStep.run(testRunner, context)

log.info res
```

And the **Add** Step this way:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>${first}</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>${second}</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And that was all. I received the response without errors:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <AddResult>100</AddResult>
      </AddResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```